# Find all possible values of $a$ for which the sequence $x_n$ converges

Tags: limits, mathematical-physics

$$x_{n+1} =\frac{x_n^2}{2} + \frac{a}{2} $$
$$x_0 = 0$$
$$x_n \rightarrow x$$ =>
$$x = \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{a}{2}$$
$$x = 1 \pm \sqrt{1-a}$$
I have already checked that for a positive value of a the sequence converges only if it is not greater than $1$.
But there were difficulties with the negative

[positive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWhUt.png)

drawn two graphs

blue $f$: $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$

black $g: x_{n+2} = g(x_n)$

noticed that when $a<-3$    $x_n$  seems to diverge

$$\{0,g(0),g(g(0)),\ldots \}= \{x_0, x_2,x_4,\ldots \}$$

$$\{a/2,g(a/2),g(g(a/2),\ldots\} = \{x_1,x_3,x_4,\ldots\}$$

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/t8m2lb9f9q

[necessary condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6nzI.png)  $-3 \le a \le 1$

Comment: my attempt https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4758845/1174783

Answer (score 0):

Consider the discrete derivative

$$x_{n+1}-x_n = \frac{(x_n+1)^2+(a-1)}{2}$$

The sequence can only converge to points where the discrete derivative is $0$ (called equilibrium or stationary points in a dynamical systems setting) which implies $a\leq 1$. However at $a=1$, the equilibrium point is not a stable point as the discrete derivative is positive on both sides.

For $a<1$, regardless of positive or negative since $a=0$ is not a bifurcation point of this system, just as you found the equilibrium points are

$$x_{\pm} = -1 \pm \sqrt{1-a}$$

However since the discrete derivative is an upward facing parabola, the positive root is an unstable equilibrium point (small perturbations away from the positive root tend to move further away) and the negative root is a stable equilibrium point (small perturbations away from the negative root tend to move closer back). This means we have the following convergences for the limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = \begin{cases}x_- & x_0 < x_+ \\ x_+ & x_0 = x_+ \\ \infty & x_0 > x_+\end{cases}$$

Edit: This answer has still not been fixed yet, but I am leaving it up to not remove the positive discussion it generated in the comments that improved my understanding of the problem and has several of OP's attempts to work at a solution.

Comment: I would have thought you needed $x_-$ when $-x_+ < x <x_+$ and $x_+$ when $|x|=x_+$

Comment: If possible, I would not like to resort to the graphical method. Need formal proof as in the attached photo

Comment: @julius this is not a proof - this merely gives motivation to actually prove the last statement at the end. You should be capable of doing this last part yourself with the heavy lifting I have already done for you. Did you understand that the $a$ value being positive or negative is not relevant?

Comment: You might check these statements, for example with $a=-8$ and varying values of $x_0$ such as $-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5$

Comment: @Henry I'm not sure I understand your comment. $-x_+$ has no geometric significance for the parabola so I don't see why it would be involved in any of the limit conditions.

Comment: @NinadMunshi If $x_0=k$ leads to divergence then $x_0=-k$ will too, as both give the same $x_1=\frac{k^2+a}{2}$

Comment: @Henry sorry i forgot to add the initial condition(

Comment: @julius That is a big change.  You might want to look at what happens with $a=-9$

Comment: @Henry I see your point now, that does make sense. I'll have to think about this some more tomorrow.

Comment: @Henry as notised positive root is not stable i.e. if for some k $x_k > 1 + \sqrt{1-a}$ => x_k -divergence and go to $\infty$ =>$-(1+\sqrt{1-a}) < a/2=x_1$ => $a>-8$

Comment: for $a=-4$  $x_0 = 0$ $x_1=-2$, $x_2 =0$...... divergence

Comment: my attempt math.stackexchange.com/a/4758845/1174783

Answer (score 0):

necessary and sufficient condition
[$0 \le a\le 1$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKSsz.png)

($a<0$) necessary condition  => [$-3 \le a < 0$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvAMH.png)

$-3 \le a \le 0 \space \space $[$\sqrt{-a} \le x_n \le 0 \space \space and \space\space x_{n}>x_{n-1} => x_{n+1}<x_n$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocM46.png)

$x_n = x_{N-1} + \Sigma_{k=N}^{n} (x_k - x_{k-1})$

and it suffices to prove the convergence of the series
[$x_{n+1}-x_n = y(t) (x_n-x_{n-1}) \space \space -3<a<0 => |y(t)| <q<1$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkZeU.png)

when $-3 < a< 0$  can choose $|\frac{a-1}{4}|<q<1$ and  $|x_{n+1} -x_n| < q|x_{n}-x_{n-1}|$ at some $n>N-1$

$|x_n| \le |x_{N-1}| + \Sigma_{k=N}^{n} |x_k - x_{k-1}|< |x_{N-1}| + |x_N-x_{N-1}| \Sigma_{k=N}^n q^{k-N} $ that is, the sequence converges

It remains to prove the convergence for a=-3

Comment: If $-3\le a\le0$ is necessary and $0\le a\le1$ is necessary and sufficient then convergence implies $a=0$ but $0\le a\le1$ implies convergence. Is that a contradiction?

Comment: @Lucenaposition actually this is a necessary condition for a < 0. in general necessary condition is $a \ge -3$